# CosmosDB SocketException for parallel queries in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

We have a web app in Azure (asp.net core 3.1) querying a CosmosDB database (with autoscale). For performance reasons, I have all queries in parallel by first creating an array of `Task<data>` and then running `Task.WhenAll(..)` to send the queries. When the array becomes too large (~3000), I often get a SocketException. Problem is that this is random, as I never get this on my local dev PC and in Azure when it works, the data is returned after a few seconds.

I Application Insights, the failing queries shows as

- First ones have a 200 response and duration of ~100 ms
- Then I can have some with 200 response and duration of 4-5 seconds
- Then comes the faulted ones with duration of ~20 seconds

The only settings I see people recommend is something like this for the CosmosDB client:

```
client = new DocumentClient(
  new Uri(..), 
  Key,
  new ConnectionPolicy()
  {
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
    IdleTcpConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0)
});
```

What other settings can be relevant? I have played around with `MaxRequestsPerTcpConnection = 16`, `OpenTcpConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0)` and `RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0)`, but none seem to have any effect.

Update 2020-10-24:

It might be that the number of connections will be a limitation for parallel connections, but I don't know how to handle this in an easy way as sometimes the query will run fine, other times not.

However, the solution was to avoid the manual parallelism and let CosmosDB handle this whatever way it's optimized to do. It's long time since I wrote those parallel queries and it was probably a trade-off between performance and RU/s as the queries are cross-partition. The code had to handle 427 errors, but this was removed when I went over to auto-scale. The parallel code is now re-written to be cross-partition with max concurrency = -1, ref. [Parallel cross-partition query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container#parallel-cross-partition-query).

Code-wise the first query was:

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyClass>(
  UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, collection),
  new FeedOptions 
  { 
    MaxItemCount = -1 
  })
  .Where(q => q.PartitionKey == partitionKey)
  .AsDocumentQuery();
```

which I added to a list of tasks for each partition key.

And then the cross-partition:

```
var partitionKeys = <list of partition keys>; 
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyClass>(
  UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, collection),
  new FeedOptions
  {
    MaxItemCount = -1,
    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1
  })
  .Where(q => partitionKeys.Contains(q.PartitionKey))
  .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: Are you seeing timeouts? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-request-timeout#troubleshooting-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into Azure App Service [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits) on simultaneous connections:

> The maximum IP connections are per instance and depend on the instance
> size: 1,920 per B1/S1/P1V3 instance, 3,968 per B2/S2/P2V3 instance,
> 8,064 per B3/S3/P3V3 instance

So, increasing the instance size could help. But that's a lot of connections to manage and throwing more scale isn't necessarily the best approach. Using the bulk support in the SDK should help consolidate these simultaneous connections:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/